# R - add plot to facetted ggplot2 object (using annotation_custom)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to inset a plot using `ggplot2` and `annotation_custom` (the plot is actually a map that I'm using to replace the legend). However, I'm also using `facet_wrap` to generate multiple panels, but when used with `annotation_custom`, this reproduces the plot in each facet. Is there an easy way to insert the plot only once, preferably outside the plotting area?

Here is a brief example:

```
#Generate fake data
set.seed(9)
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),facets=rep(letters[1:2]),
              colors=rep(c("red","blue"),each=50))
#Create base plot
p=ggplot(df,aes(x,y,col=colors))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~facets)
#Create plot to replace legend
legend.plot=ggplotGrob(
  ggplot(data=data.frame(colors=c("red","blue"),x=c(1,1),y=c(1,2)),
         aes(x,y,shape=colors,col=colors))+geom_point(size=16)+
         theme(legend.position="none") )
#Insert plot using annotation_custom
p+annotation_custom(legend.plot)+theme(legend.position="none") 
#this puts plot on each facet!
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: plot1]
When I would like something more along the lines of:
[image: plotideal]
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the help of `annotation_custom()` it is said that annotations `"are the same in every panel"`, so it is expected result to have your legend.plot in each facet (panel).

One solution is to add `theme(legend.position="none")` to your base plot and then use `grid.arrange()` (library `gridExtra`) to plot both plots.

```
library(gridExtra)
p=ggplot(df,aes(x,y,col=colors))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~facets)+
         theme(legend.position="none") 

grid.arrange(p,legend.plot,ncol=2,widths=c(3/4,1/4))
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it does say that. `grid.arrange` appears to the be the best way to go -- thanks !